# Observable error handling by Angular's ExceptionHandler

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-http

I would like Angular's ExceptionHandler to handle any errors that occur from API calls. The problem is they never reach the ExceptionHandler's handleError method and I'm not sure what I need to do different.

```
// data.service.ts

addItem(name: string): Observable<any> {

  return this.http.post(name)
           .map(this.extractData)
           .catch((error) => this.handleError(error))
           .share(); 
}

private handleError(error: any): any {
  const msg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}`

  // this did not work
  //throw new Error(msg); 

  // also doesn't work
  return Observable.throw(new Error(msg));
}

// item.component.ts

 const observable = this.dataService.addItem('test');
 observable.subscribe(
   (success) => console.log('success'),
   (error) => { throw new Error('test'); // doesn't work }
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like zone is not able to catch the error to pass it to Angular ErrorHandler. May be map will do the trick.

```
     return this.http.post(name)
       .map(this.extractData)
       .catch((error) => this.handleError(error))
       .map(result=> {
         if(result === 'good one') { return 'good one'; }
         else { new Error(result);}
       })
       .share();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put just like this:

```
.catch(this.handleError);
```

Example:

```
    public fetch(url, env = null): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.buildURL(url, env))
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm why should that matter? I did catch((error) => this.handleError(error)) because eventually I would to be able to pass my own custom messasge to show instead.